# windows SSD caffe

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

everyone,when I test [`ssd_pascal_video.py`](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/ssd/examples/ssd/ssd_pascal_video.py) in windows,I got the following error:

```
    E:\caffe-ssd-microsoft\Build\x64\Release\pycaffe>python E:\caffe-ssd-microsoft\examples\ssd\ssd_pascal_webcam.py --cpu
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\caffe-ssd-microsoft\examples\ssd\ssd_pascal_webcam.py", line 151, in <module>
  for file in os.listdir(snapshot_dir):
     WindowsError: [Error 3] : 'models/VGGNet/VOC0712/SSD_300x300/*.*'
```

then,I check the ssd_pascal_video.py,I find the following code,I can't understand the meaning of "{}"in the address.

```
   # The job name should be same as the name used in examples/ssd/ssd_pascal.py.
   job_name = "SSD_{}".format(resize)
   # The name of the model. Modify it if you want.
   model_name = "VGG_VOC0712_{}".format(job_name)

   # Directory which stores the model .prototxt file.
  save_dir = "models/VGGNet/VOC0712/{}_video".format(job_name)
  # Directory which stores the snapshot of trained models.
  snapshot_dir = "models/VGGNet/VOC0712/{}".format(job_name)
  # Directory which stores the job script and log file.
  job_dir = "jobs/VGGNet/VOC0712/{}_video".format(job_name)

  # model definition files.
  test_net_file = "{}/test.prototxt".format(save_dir)
  # snapshot prefix.
  snapshot_prefix = "{}/{}".format(snapshot_dir, model_name)
  # job script path.
  job_file = "{}/{}.sh".format(job_dir, model_name)

  # Find most recent snapshot.
  max_iter = 0
  for file in os.listdir(snapshot_dir):
  if file.endswith(".caffemodel"):
  basename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
  iter = int(basename.split("{}_iter_".format(model_name))[1])
  if iter > max_iter:
   max_iter = iter
```

Answer (score 0):

The `'{}'` in the strings in part of the [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) operator in python.
Basically, each `{}` in string is replaced by the corresponding value in the `.format()`.

Comment: Hello,Shai! Why it didn't give a full address?How can I solve this problem? Do I use a false address?

Comment: @H.Hao did you downloaded pre-trained models? does the folder `'models/VGGNet/VOC0712/SSD_300x300'` exists (note this is a **relative** path to your current working directory)?

Comment: I download the model,and my address is models/VGGNet/VOC0712/SSD_300×300.But in the ssd_pascal_video.py, I can't find the SSD_300×300 should be locate in which file,I just read the official introduction to locate the file in my address.