# Run SSD on ssd-windows branch issues

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I use ssd-windows branch on windows 10,I compiled it successfully.But when I run the **ssd_pascal_video.py**,I got an error below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\caffe-ssd-microsoft\examples\ssd\ssd_pascal_video.py", line 153, in <module>
 iter = int(basename.split("{}_iter_".format(model_name))[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The following is the code address.

https://github.com/conner99/caffe

Someone know the reason? Thank you!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672251/windows-ssd-caffe

Comment: can you show the content of your `snapshot_dir`? are you sure you properly downloaded all models **and** their weights? Have you renamed nay files?

Comment: sorry,my computer can't reply you in time.My snapshot_dir is "models/VGGNet/VOC0712/{ }".and I didn't change it,last time I run python didn't in caffe_root,so it occurred the error yesterday,but this time, I checked the file address,I have run it today,and it generated the"jobs"file,you can see from the ssd_pascal_video.py,but the windows tell me "jobs" isn't inner comand and can't be deal with.

Comment: What?? please edit your question to reflect any new information you have. If the error cannot be reproduce, you may consider deleting the question.

Comment: @Shai   Thank you for your help, It seems it runs very well in others,but for me,it always appear errors,and the error "jobs is not inner comand and can't be deal with" has disappeared and the above error appered,namely,IndexError

Comment: @Shai   Could you give me your email,so I can talk it in detail. Thank you very much!